# Composer update failed: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: magento, composer-php

I tried to install compose on my pc with Mac OS
On terminal, I typed command "composer update", and it occurs errors bellow.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Initializing PEAR repository https://pear.php.net
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.5 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.5].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.5 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.10, 2.4.11,2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Comment: Do you have zendframework/zend-stdlib in composer?

Comment: Yes, I have. Composer contains that.